# Chern class of fiber bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I have a fiber bunde $F\to E\stackrel \pi \to B$ and i want to calculate its first Chern class $c_1(E)=c_1(TE)$. How can i do this?

I read [here](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/Tangent_bundles_of_bundles_(Ex)), that 
$$TE \stackrel \sim = \pi^* TB \oplus T_\pi E, $$
where $T_\pi E$ consists of the tangent vectors tangent to the fibers.

So $$c_1(TE)= \pi^* c_1(TB) + c_1(T_\pi E).$$

Its clear how to calculate $\pi^* c_1(TB)$, but what about $c_1(T_\pi E)$?
Is it true that $c_1(T_\pi E)= c_1(TF)$?. The bundle $T_\pi E$ seems to be in some sense $B\times TF$, but i don't know how to make this precise.

Comment: You have that $T_\pi E$ is isomorphic to $\pi^* E$ I believe. This can be shown using local trivializations for example.

Comment: This is also related to Question 0.2 in the source you mentioned.

Comment: @ThorbenK What do you mean with $\pi^*E$? $\pi$ is a map from $E$ to $B$.

Comment: You pull the vector bundle $E$ over $B$ back along $\pi$ to get a new vector bundle $\pi^* E$ over $E$.

Comment: @ThorbenK hm...this might work. The problem is, $E$ is not a vector bundle.

Comment: OK. I don't know why I assumed that you have a vector bundle. I don't know what a satisfying answer would be for you since the cohomology of the total space of a fiber bundle can be quite complicated.

Comment: ThorbenK's answer works if $E\rightarrow B$ is a vector bundle (and can also be massaged to work if $F$ is a sphere and the structure group is linear, etc.).  If the inclusion map $i:F\rightarrow E$ induces an injection $H^1(E)\rightarrow H^1(F)$, then using the fact that $i^\ast(T_\pi E) = TF$, you know that $i^\ast c_1(T_\pi E) = c_1(F)$, then you can compute $c_1(T_\pi E)$.

Comment: The sense in which $T_\pi E$ is "like" $B \times TF$ is that you replace the $F$ fibres of $E$ with copies of $TF$. This idea can be made precise with the [Homotopy Quotient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivariant_cohomology#Homotopy_quotient) (aka Borel Construction). The structure group of the bundle $E$ is $Diff(F)$,  which also acts on $TF$. If $P_{D}E$ denotes the underlying principal $Diff(F)$ bundle of $E$ then $T_\pi E \cong P_{D}E \times_{Diff(F)} TF$. This might not necessarily help to compute anything though, but I hoped to clear up that ambiguity.

Comment: @JasonDeVito: Thank you, this is applicable to my case. We need an injection $H^2(E)\to H^2(F)$ though, right?

Comment: Yes - not sure why I made the super script 1!